# Kendo Grid with kendoDrop down list

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

To include dropdown list in KendoGrid was easy by using fore  [foreign key editor](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn) but what i want is create a fully working kendoDropdown list with events as editor template of Kendo Grid. And I want to achieve that by using HTML5 and Javascript only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, i do have code in using foreign key, and editor template using asp.net razor. using fully javascript, i dont know where to begin with. and there's no resources/example found in web.

Comment: post what you've got? create a fiddle or something? the answer below is a starting point.  if you want more, show where you are now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom column editor http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "name",
    editor: function(container, options) {
     var input = $("<input/>");
     input.attr("name", options.field);
     input.appendTo(container);
     input.kendoDropDownList({
         ....
     });
    }
  } ],
  editable: true,
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @Gene R for guiding me right! I just what I achieve so far,

it this example, I have two combo box, the fruit and its type, in which the type was dependent on fruit selected.

```js
 var productType = ["injan", "pico", "green", "candy"];
 var productList = ["Mango", "Citrus", "Banana"];
 var summary = [{
   ProductName: "Mango",
   Type: "Piko",
   Discontinued: true,
   ReorderLevel: 2
 }, {
   ProductName: "Citrus",
   Type: "Orange",
   Discontinued: true,
   ReorderLevel: 4
 }];
 var productDs = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   data: productType
 });

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: {
       data: summary,
       pageSize: 20
     },
     height: 550,
     scrollable: true,
     sortable: true,
     filterable: true,
     pageable: {
       input: true,
       numeric: false
     },
     columns: [{
         field: "ProductName",
         editor: function(container, options) {
           var input = $("<input/>");
           input.attr("name", options.field);
           input.appendTo(container);
           input.kendoDropDownList({
             dataSource: productList,
             change: productChange
           });
         }
       }, {
         field: "Type",
         editor: function(container, options) {
           var input = $("<input/>");
           input.attr("name", options.field);
           input.appendTo(container);
           input.kendoDropDownList({
             dataSource: productDs
           });
         }
       },
       //{ field: "Type", values: productType},
       {
         field: "ReorderLevel",
         width: "80px",
         hidden: false
       }, {
         field: "Discontinued",
         width: "80px",
         template: '<input type="checkbox" #= Discontinued ? checked="checked" : "" # disabled="disabled" ></input>'
       }, {
         command: ["destroy", "edit"],
         title: "&nbsp;"
       }
     ],
     editable: "popup"
       //toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"]
   });
 });

 function productChange(e) {
   var fruit = e.sender.dataItem(this.selectedIndex);
   if (fruit == "Mango")
     productType = ["injan", "pico", "green", "candy"];
   else if (fruit == "Citrus")
     productType = ["Orange", "Lemon", "Dalandan", "Sunkist"];
   else
     productType = ["Lakatan", "La Tundan", "Standard"];

   console.log(fruit);
   productDs.data(productType);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.black.min.css" />
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```